# Is there a way to automatically map existing web.config settings if I'm deploying an existing Web App to Azure?

Tags: web-config, azure-web-app-service

I have an existing ASP.Net MVC app that's currently hosted locally in IIS and I'm trying to deploy it to an Azure App Service.

I've seen several posts about setting the Applications Settings and Connection Strings manually in the *Application Settings* blade.

The problem with that is that I have a ton of App settings in my web.config file, along with various other config sections.

Is there a way to automatically map those to Azure Application Settings when I deploy my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to write a simple transform tool that changes those web.config based settings into the equivalent ARM template that sets those settings and connection strings (probably < 20 lines of code).

Note that there is no Azure equivalent of sections other than App Settings and Connection Strings.